# Tips for removing a handle point from a complex mesh

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I have some complex meshes imported from photogrammetry which I am trying to clean up in Blender. One of the artefacts that sometimes arises is when two parts of the mesh incorrectly join to each other creating a handle point. I need to remove these so the meshes have genus 0.

[image: handle point]

This is one example. I want to remove the highlighted "pillar" so that the upper and lower parts in view here stay separate from each other.

I have been able to bodge together a method in edit mode using knife cuts, deleting faces, and then filling holes using grid fill, but it is quite laborious and the resulting geometry does not match the surroundings well. As far as I'm aware there aren't any tools in sculpting mode that will change the fundamental topology in this way. Any suggestions for how to do this without too much micro-management of individual vertices, and leaving a natural-looking result?

Comment: What do you mean with "there aren't any sculpting tools that will change the fundamental topology"? What is the 'fundamental topology'?

Comment: @Joachim From my understanding (but I'm a relative beginner) sculpting will change the relative positions of vertices but won't alter their connectivity. The topology of the network of vertices and edges will remain the same. In particular, it won't take you from genus 1 to genus 0.

Comment: Imagine a figure with a hand on their hip, with the hand and hip "fused" within the mesh, joined by edges and faces. I want to separate the hand from the hip. I don't think sculpting will do that, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Sculpt mode* has a few tools to do this. One of them is

**Trim tool** (Box or Laso).

[image]

or

**Flatten tool** (with Dyntopo enabled)

[image]